# Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::store

Tags: php, laravel

I upload my project in the host. I uploaded an image, and the image save in database. And the image did not show well, but it show in my localhost as well.

config/filesystem.php

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/link', function(){
    return Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

It return show 0.

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $path = $user->image ?? null;
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $nane = time();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $nane . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $file->storeAs('images/users', $fileName, 'public');
    }
    $user->image = $path;
}
```

The image save in database.

The image uploaded in storage/app/public/images/users folder.

The image did not uploaded public/images/users.

Then I change this

```
 $path = Storage::disk('public')->store('images/users/'.$fileName);
```

I get this code

[image: error]

Comment: store and storeAs are methods available on UploadedFile while on Storage the available methods are put, putFile and putFileAs

Comment: This is my first time working with Laravel. If you know you can put the code here?

Answer (score 1):

**Storage** facade

```php
//Will store the uploaded image in /storage/app/public/images/users
$path = Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('images/users', $file, $fileName);
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files

**UploadedFile**

```php
//Will store the uploaded image in /storage/app/public/images/users
$path = $request->image->storeAs('images/users', $filename, 'public');
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Little refactor for the update method

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    
    if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid())
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $nane = time();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $nane . '.' . $extension;
        $user->image = $file->storeAs('images/users', $fileName, 'public');

    }

    $user->save();
   
}
```

Comment: I want to upload in storage did not public

Comment: I added `filesystem.php` in my post

Comment: @irankhostravi Have updated my answer. "The image did not uploaded public/images/users" made me think that you want to store the images in **/public** - got confused, sorry about that

Comment: @irankhostravi Have updated answer with little refactor in the update method. Let me know if everything works as per your expectation now

Comment: I tried all three methods, none of them work

Comment: What is the issue? When you say none of them work - is the uploaded image not getting stored at the intended path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225438/discussion-between-irankhostravi-and-donkarnash).

Comment: Plaease go to chat